# recursing filter array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter

i have array:

```
[
 {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'},
 {id: 2, name: 'Child1', parent: {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'}},
 {id: 3, name: 'Child2', parent: {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'}},
 {id: 4, name: 'GrandChild1', parent: {id: 3, name: 'Child2'}},
 {id: 5, name: 'GrandChild2', parent: {id: 3, name: 'Child2'}}
]
```

I need to write a function with an id argument that will return an array that does not include the element with id and all of its children and children of childrens. Help pls

I tries write recursing function but fallen

Comment: `function myfilter(id, nodes) { return nodes.filter(n => n.id != id && n.parent?.id != id) }`

Comment: @Mulan the function should filter the children of the children

Comment: Please show the desired result, and your failing attempt.

Comment: btw, why not take only the id for the parent instead of the object?

Comment: @Barmar for exmaple, if u call function with id = 1 u should get empty array. Or if u call func with id 3 u should get array with two objects (id: 1 and id: 2)

Comment: @NinaScholz Good idea, but not in the context of this problem

Comment: I don't get why you store the `name` twice:  Each element has a `name` property, but also the `parent` property is an object that also has a `name` property. But this object does not have a `parent` property.  .i.e., the value of the `parent` seems not to be the parent object itself, but rather a new object that has the same `id` as the parent, Presumably you have to search the array to find the matching object that corresponds to that id to get the matching object.  It may be appropriate to build an index (from id to object) first depending on performance.

Comment: @SergeyGrenaderov That clarification should be in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the unwanted parents for later filtering out.

This approach works for unsorted items.

```js
const
    filter = (array, id) => {
        const
            parents = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ id, parent = {} }) => [id, parent.id])),
            isParent = pid => id === parents[pid] || pid in parents && isParent(parents[pid]);
        return array.filter(o => o.id !== id && !isParent(o.id));
    },
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Parent1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Child1', parent: { id: 1, name: 'Parent1' } }, { id: 3, name: 'Child2', parent: { id: 1, name: 'Parent1' } }, { id: 4, name: 'GrandChild1', parent: { id: 3, name: 'Child2' } }, { id: 5, name: 'GrandChild2', parent: { id: 3, name: 'Child2' } }];

console.log(filter(data, 1));
console.log(filter(data, 2));
console.log(filter(data, 3));
console.log(filter(data, 4));
console.log(filter(data, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ur function good for sorted elements, but in my array parent can be in mid element(

Answer (score 1):

That is how I would approach the problem

```
let values = [
 {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'},
 {id: 2, name: 'Child1', parent: {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'}},
 {id: 3, name: 'Child2', parent: {id: 1, name: 'Parent1'}},
 {id: 4, name: 'GrandChild1', parent: {id: 3, name: 'Child2'}},
 {id: 5, name: 'GrandChild2', parent: {id: 3, name: 'Child2'}},
 {id: 6, name: 'GreatGrandChild', parent: {id: 5, name: 'GrandChild2'}},
 {id: 11, name: 'Parent2'},
 {id: 12, name: 'Child1ToParent2', parent: {id: 11, name: 'Parent2'}},
 {id: 13, name: 'Child2ToParent2', parent: {id: 11, name: 'Parent2'}},
 {id: 14, name: 'GrandChild1ToParent2', parent: {id: 13, name: 'Child2ToParent2'}},
 {id: 15, name: 'GrandChild2ToParent2', parent: {id: 13, name: 'Child2ToParent2'}},
 {id: 16, name: 'GreatGrandChildToParent2', parent: {id: 15, name: 'GrandChild2ToParent2'}},
]

function isDescendant(idRoot, node) {
    // If no parent, it is one of the roots of the family tree so we return false
    if (!node.parent) {
        return false;
    }

    // Else, finds the parent in the list.
    const parent = values.find(value => value.id === node.parent.id);

    //Checks if it is the right parent.
    if (idRoot === parent.id) {
        return true;
    }

    // Is a great children -> continue recursively
    return isDescendant(idRoot, parent);
}

let filteredValues = values.filter(x => isDescendant(1, x))
console.log(filteredValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const validArr = item => typeof item.age === 'number' && item.age > 17;

const thisWontWork = arr => {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    if (item.id) {
      // here is the recursive call
      return thisWontWork(item.id).length > 0 && validArr(item);
    } else return validArr(item);
  });
};
    
log(thisWontWork(name));
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? Where does your function look for a given ID?

Answer (score -1):

```
function filterByIdAndChildren(id, arr) {
  const filteredArray = [];

  function filterItems(inputId, array) {
    for (const item of array) {
      if (item.id !== inputId) {
        if (item.parent && item.parent.id === inputId) {
          filterItems(item.id, array);
        } else {
          filteredArray.push(item);
          if (item.parent) {
            filterItems(inputId, [item.parent]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  filterItems(id, arr);
  return filteredArray;
}
```

it should be work!

Comment: No, If you call it with id 1 then u will get array [{id:4, id: 5}], but this incorrect

Comment: I fixed it. Check it out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).